# Can a Nexus 7 connect to an Android 2.2 Wi-Fi tethering access point?

Tags: 2.2-froyo, nexus-7, wifi-tethering, samsung-galaxy-5, usb-tethering

I am considering buying a Nexus 7. I would like to occasionally be able to access the internet out and about, but don't want to pay 50% again to get the hspa+ version.

I have a Samsung Galaxy Europa I5500 (a.k.a Samsung Galaxy 5) which allows wi-fi (and USB) tethering to provide my laptop with internet. My question is: would a Nexus 7 16GB Wi-Fi be able to connect to the Android 2.2 access point created by my Galaxy Europa?

If this isn't possible, would USB tethering be an option still?

Thanks,
Chris

Comment: Why should it not? That's what the Hotspot functionality is for.

Comment: @Izzy I have never managed to tether my brother's HTC Desire HD to my Galaxy Europa, I was worried that this might be the case with Android to Android connections in general. It is not!

Comment: At least it should not be, in general. There always might be some exceptions, sure, one never knows what can go wrong. But in general, it should work -- as that is what it's designed for :)

Answer (score 1):

I managed to get my hands on one to test this and Wi-Fi tethering between the two worked fine, no apps required.

Comment: Would be worth accepting your solution as the answer Chris since you've actually tested it.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, that is how I occasionally browse on my Nexus 7. I use this app called as `OpenGarden` which has a very clean interface and uses VPN via Bluetooth to connect to your internet enabled open.

NOTE: You need OpenGarden on your phone too. Don't worry. It's a free app!

Comment: Don't know why [Open Garden](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.opengarden.android.MeshClient) should be a conditional here: One Android device provides the hotspot, and the other (Nexus 7 in this case) just uses it as it would any other WiFi network. No additional apps required -- see the OP's own answer.

Comment: Of course you don't need to. Just because there's Internet Explorer, it doesn't mean that you don't need Google Chrome! ;-)

Comment: So it's not "you need", but rather "it's nice to have" :)